# Update ... Where ...Inner Join

Tags: sql, oracle11g, sql-update

I've been trying to find a way to update my records by doing an inner join... but haven't been able to find any documentation on it.

Here is my query so far.

```
update TBL1 set carga = '2016-11' where  (
select h.CASEID 
from TBL1
h inner join TBL2 t 
on h.caseid = t.caseid)
```

Comment: You might be missing this where TBL1.CASEID IN = (...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want `exists`:

```
update TBL1
    set carga = '2016-11'
    where exists (select 1
                  from TBL2 t 
                  where TBL1.caseid = t.caseid
                 );
```

You could also use `in`:

```
update TBL1
    set carga = '2016-11'
    where caseid in (select t.caseid from TBL2 t);
```

Comment: The first method changed all my rows on TBL1, trying the second method now

Comment: The second method gave me the correct answer. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing "TBL1.CASEID = " from your where clause:

```
update TBL1 set carga = '2016-11' where TBL1.CASEID =  (
select h.CASEID 
from TBL1
h inner join TBL2 t 
on h.caseid = t.caseid)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need a MERGE:

```
merge into TBL1 t1
using ( select * from TBL2) t2
on ( t1.caseid = t2.caseid)
when matched then
  update set carga = '2016-11'
```